# With MediaCodec API, i'm getting OutputBufferIndex as -1 everytime. Any possible solution?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

```
mediacodec init:
mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
mediaFormat.setInteger("color-format", 19);
mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, paramSurface, null, 0);
int i = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(this.bufferInfo, 0L);

    if (i >= 0)
    {
        int j = i;             

        mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(j, true);

        if ((this.bufferInfo.flags & 0x4) != 0)
            Log.d(TAG, "BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");

        return ;

    }
    else if (i == -3)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
        outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
    }
    else if (i == -2)
    {
        MediaFormat localMediaFormat = mediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
        Log.d(TAG, "Output format has changed to " + localMediaFormat);
        Log.d(TAG, "Output format width:" + localMediaFormat.getInteger("width"));
        Log.d(TAG, "Output format height:" + localMediaFormat.getInteger("height"));                    
    }
    else if(i==-1){         
        Log.d(TAG, "dequeueOutputBuffer timeout pts is " + pts);        
    }
```

Comment: The code above doesn't show how you are providing data to the decoder.  Make sure you're supplying the CSD data and passing one access unit per buffer.  See also http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Comment: I get the data from the ffmpeg. And I fill the inputbuffer with a video packet at a time. The codes work good except the ZTE Z987 mobile. How could i sove it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant ZTE V987 in the comment, the [specs I found](http://www.gsmarena.com/zte_grand_x_quad_v987-5376.php) say it runs Android 4.1.2 with a PowerVR GPU, but don't say who the video IP is from, so it's give a definitive answer.  However, I think the problem is that you're hard-coding the color format to 19 (planar YUV 420), and some devices don't support that.

For example, if the PVR GPU is paired with TI video (as it was in the Galaxy Nexus), you'd likely need `COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar` (a semi-planar format).  You may see some relevant messages in the logcat output.

If you look at the `encodeDecodeVideoFromBuffer()` method in the CTS [EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest) you can see how it uses `selectColorFormat()` method to pick the color format.  If you can't configure ffmpeg to deliver data in this format you'll have to do your own conversion.  See the `generateFrame()` method for information about the layout.